# Issue with a batch file I created. It adds a user correctly but won't remove

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 40 .txt files that are named after 40 of my users computer and each .txt file contains a users AD account. The following bat script works great at injecting the ad account to the administrator group.

```
mkdir "c:\newtemp\a_accounts"
xcopy "\\SERVERNAME\FOLDER\a_accounts\%computername%.txt" "c:\newtemp\a_accounts"
for /f "usebackq" %%X in ("c:\newtest\a_accounts\delete\%computername%.txt") do (NET LOCALGROUP ADMINISTRATORS %%X /add)
```

However, if I make a new bat file and reverse the switch from /add to /delete It doesn't work on the new script. I have to use the script above to be able to delete other users from the local admin group.

```
mkdir "c:\newtemp\delete_user_admin"
xcopy "\\SERVERNAME\FOLDER\delete_user_admin\%computername%.txt" "c:\newtemp\delete_user_admin"
For /F "usebackq" %%G IN ("c:\newtemp\delete_user_admin\%computername%.txt") DO (NET LOCALGROUP ADMINISTRATORS %%G /delete)
```

When the for /f runs it doesn't do anything (no errors neither. It just shows the line). Which has me stunned as to why it is behaving this way. I tried changing the variable from X to another letter but this does nothing different. Any clue why this is happening?

Okay so it looks like the variable is not picking up the user name in the file. I just replaced the second %%G with my ad username and ran the script and it deleted my account from the local admin. Now gotta figure out why the for /f is not working. Looking at the website I am using the correct lines.

7/17/2016

Yeah I am completely stomp why this isn't working. Ran both lines together in a .bat and the following happens.

This works fine.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%X in ("c:\newtemp\a_accounts\%computername%.txt") do (NET LOCALGROUP ADMINISTRATORS %%X /add)
```

However, if I change the folder it breaks (no errors just does nothing but look like it runs the line but produces nothing.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%X in ("c:\newtemp\a_accounts2\%computername%.txt") do (NET LOCALGROUP ADMINISTRATORS %%X /delete)
```

If I go into the .bat file and edit the second line to point to the first folder "a_accounts" and flip the /add to /delete the line works fine!!! Makes no sense what's so ever. I have lost all hope of being able to understand why this isn't working as it should unless someone has the answer.

Comment: Where does bash come into this?  And tip: take a sharp look at the syntax highlighting in your second code sample here, you might spot the answer to your problem...

Comment: Oops meant to say batch (how embarrassing) and hmm updated the lines since I made a mistake by adding the %computername% after the mkdir that was me trying different things but yeah I am give it another go at it so far I am still confused and lost.

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdist stuff I seen in my life. If I copy the txt file from the working script and modify the name the second line works!!! WHAT!!!!?? Makes no sense but I got it to work the way I want.

Answer (score 0):

You copy to `c:\newtemp\delete_user_admin\%computername%` yet you read from `"c:\newtemp\delete_user_admin\%computername%.txt"`

These are not the same.

Comment: Thank you, wrote the lines wrong on here. Edited the mistake and look it is correct how I have it on the .bat file. Mind looking at it?

Comment: Now neither of your scripts will work.  They're both missing a `)` on the line that runs `net use`.  You're best off copy-n-pasting from your source script, otherwise we'll keep tracking down typos.

Comment: You are right, I copy and pasted the correct lines instead of typing it! Sorry still learning this forum!